# Java Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing an algorithm where I need to compare java AST nodes and I use the safeSubtreeMatch method to compare the nodes. I am facing the below issue.

The SafeSubTreeMatch method works fine for the TypeDeclaration AST node if there is no constructor in the TypeDeclaration unit. If the TypeDeclaration contains constructors, then the safeSubtreeMatch method returns false even though I have passed same TypeDeclaration AST node to compare.

What is the reason behind this? Can anyone please tell if there are any other way to compare Java AST nodes?

Comment: You might want to mention which library you are using to create the AST

Comment: Looks like the class is deprecated; any particular reason why you're still using it?

Comment: I need to compare the AST nodes. Is there any other way to compare AST nodes?